# How can I label an alert to know to whom it is intended in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm working on Prometheus for my internship and I encountered a simple problem :
My boss wants to alert the staff based on what services they use. So for example the recruiters needs only the "down "alerts from some services, the sales people from some others services, etc.

(for example, if service 1 crash, the recruiters and the sales teams needs to be notified, but not the vendors because they don't need that service.)

So I need to be able to give targets MULTIPLE value to a single label, which from what I keep reading isn't possible. (something like : service: "recruiters","sales")

How can I do that? to be able to give a target a label multiple values based on who uses it?

Thank you in advance for your answer,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three solutions:

1. give names to the use cases and send email(s) depending on alert category

```
    - alert: ServiceIsDegraded
      labels:
        impact: client-level
```

2. use multiple labels representing the teams with action(s) associated to teams.

```
    - alert: ServerLost
      labels:
        dev_team: inform
        infra_support: page
```

3. use a label value which represents multiple entries and then use a regex in alert manager to identify them.

```
    - alert: ClientDoesntSeeThatYet
      labels:
        notify: SUP,DEV,SRE,SOMEONE
```

From the [data model](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/#metric-names-and-labels), you can use any separator:

> Label values may contain any Unicode characters.

In alert manager, you can match the group using word boundary:

```
route:
  - receiver: 'support'
    match_re:
      notify: \bSUP\b
  - receiver: 'dev-team'
    match_re:
      notify: \bDEV\b
```

The solution 1 requires quite a bit of work and is suitable if you have any formal definition of your alert cases. The solution 2 gives you flexibility in terms of notification medium but may be verbose.

Solution 3 looks like what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer my initial problem :
I have a set of rules, to which I could add labels, yes, but this means a rules is linked to a label. This is not what I want, let me explain:

Comment: Let's say I have the rule "target Down" because up=0, Each target that is down will trigger this rule. Let's say Target A and B. If target A fails, i need to alert recruiters, if target B fails only the admins. But all of this is within the same alert in Prometheus, so if I label like your example shows, the label will be the same no matter what target triggered the rule, I hope my explanation is comprehensible..